# What distribution family would best fit this graph?

Tags: distributions, curve-fitting

Sorry if this type of question is not kosher. I'm new around here, so please forgive me.

Anyway, I have a dataset that describes the probability that users will like certain articles from my corpus *(with 5 articles chosen randomly and graphed below. Along the x axis are individual users, and along the y-axis their score. The users are sorted by score.)*

I'm looking to fit a distribution to each line, but am unsure of which one to choose that would likely best these lines. I was thinking of using an exponential distribution? But there's a lot of information that exponential probably would not capture here. Does anyone have a good idea?

EDIT: I will update my title to include the name of a reasonable distribution so that this question will be more searchable and others would possibly learn from it in the future.

[image]

Comment: After some research, I think it's similar to a sigmoid curve, except flipped?

Comment: Probably, a sigmoid curve isn't a distribution, though. You may have an [empirical cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) (ECDF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To many statisticians, information like this would usually be thought of as an empirical CDF:

[image]

with the scores on the x-axis, and the proportion of people scoring it less than or equal to a given x-value on the y-axis (that is, your x-axis ranks become scaled to proportions of people scoring no more than the person with that rank, and then becomes the new y-axis).

But it's sometimes difficult to identify good approximating distributions from the ECDF; it might be easier to look initially at some other displays (histograms with plenty of bins, kernel density estimates, Q-Q plots or other distributional plots.

You don't say what the range of possible scores is, but I presume they're bounded. If so, a scaled beta distribution might be a reasonable starting model:

[image]

As you see, with appropriate choices for the 4 parameters (I didn't try to fit these, just tried some values roughly in the right region), they can look quite similar to at least 4 of the 5 distributions you have there. However, they're probably not suitable in general. Mixture distributions might get you further along.

On the other hand you have a lot of data, so the empirical distribution probably has all you need to answer all kinds of questions about the data.

Comment: thank you so much @Glen_b. I'm so sorry I wasn't more specific, but I'm mainly looking for a parameterized model, which empirical cdf doesn't look to be? I'll start with Beta distribution. I'll keep the question open for a bit longer and then accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Glen_b I've been turning my head sideways for about 5 minutes trying to see how Alex's plot is an ECDF, and I'm not seeing it. The x axis is user ID's and the y axis looks like a logit transform (except sorted backwards). It seems like "probability of like" is a decreasing function of user ID. I think the resemblance to an ECDF is incidental.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Unless I missed something, the numbers on OP's x-axis appears to be (effectively) ranks rather than IDs. If you take all the individual scores in a sample in order, then a plot of their scores against the values $1,2,..., n$ is (up to interchanging y and x, possible axis flipping and some scaling, possibly including a known shift) the same as the ECDF. The rank of a user corresponds to the number of users who score at least as extreme as they do, so a user's ranking can be scaled to the proportion $\leq$ than that user's score.

Comment: Alex - what do you need from a parameterized model you can't get from the sample? Incidentally a beta won't fit your green one there. Looks like a second mode near 0.8

Comment: @Glen_b Got it. With regard to the OP wanting a parameterized distribution, interpreting CDFs isn't that easy. I think a kernel density might be more natural. Maybe a triangular one to be more "empirical." And as regards bounds on the scores, I still suspect the scores are unbounded transformations of the probabilities, although that is up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: @ssdecontrol when you say "I think a kernel density might be more natural", I completely agree -- which is why it was one of several alternatives to the ECDF already mentioned in my answer (see the para that starts "But sometimes it's difficult..."), any of which might be more easily intepreted. As for what the scores really represent, again, I agree that it would be important to be clear about what they actually are.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b and ssdecontrol, I'm terribly sorry for the delay. The scores represent the dot product of a user's preferred topic score, and the article's topic score—I'm working on a recommendation algorithm based on CTM and LDA topic scores. What we are trying to model how well some articles appear to resonate with a small-but-passionate group of users. In other words, the more "niche" an article is, the higher the top user-article similarity will be, and—theoretically—the steeper the dropoff will be.

Comment: My original plan was to derive a single parameter—say the lambda of an exponential distribution—that would be a good proxy for "nicheness". Then, I'd use this in a training set along with article features like "keyword" or "byline" to build a model that would predict, before an article is published, how "niche" it would be. 

Thus, reducing the dimensionality of these lines down to a single scalar was very appealing to me, as the scalar would work well in a regression model.

Again, I am new at this, so I admit this may be simplistic thinking. Your advice is very much appreciated nonetheless!

Comment: I don't see how a single parameter would describe those distributions. If there was some single aspect of those distributions you were trying to capture, perhaps.